# get ajax response to outer variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am doing an ajax call in the following manner and I want to get the response to an outer variable but I dont want to have async as false as

> [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Please help me regarding how to do this without having async as false

```
let getUser = (emailID) =>{
    let userData;
    let json ={
        'email': emailID
    };
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type:'post',
        url:'getUserDetails.php',
        data: {userEmailAddress:json},
        success:function(response){
            if(response.status == 'success'){
               userData = response.DATA;
            }else if(response.status == 'error'){
                console.log('Failed');
                console.log(response);
            }
        },
        error:function(response){
            console.log('ajax fail');
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
    console.log(userData);
    return userData;
    };
```

Comment: Short answer, don't do it this way. Use the asynchronous callback pattern properly.

Comment: What are you wanting to do with `userData` after this?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you please provide me some resource regarding the same

Comment: I've linked to two duplicate questions which show how you can do this. Check the yellow box at the top of your question

Comment: @thebluefox I would be returning it to another function which will be carrying forward with other processings